# PyCharm warns for unresolved reference builtin datetime module

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed the latest version of PyCharm (4.5).

Now I am experiencing unresolved reference errors.
On the top of my code I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

OS is Ubuntu 15.04.
Already did the Invalidate Cache/Restart several times. No difference.
The Project interpreter of my project is set to Python 2.7.6.
Already reloaded the Interperter Paths.

Code works fine, it's just the IDE that produces an annoying error and no more autocomplete.

Comment: have you tried to rebuild the framework skeletons? you could also try to remove the .idea folder and re-open a project to see if it helps

Comment: Hedde, I rebuilt the skeletons and also removed the .idea folder. Same result.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it, perhaps try to create a virtualenv and point your project to it, repeat the cache steps and see if it changes anything, it must have something todo with the interpreter settings imo

Comment: it works fine for me in 14.04 i know for sure ... but i have the paid version (doubt that makes a difference here)

Comment: I also have the paid version. Has been working on 14.04 for me as well. Last weekend I upgraded to 15.04 and right after that installed PyCharm 4.5. Since then this error occured.

Comment: same on Idea 15.04....

Comment: There is reported bug in jetbrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15460

Comment: Problem solved after upgrading to Pycharm 5.0.1.

Comment: Anyone else have this issue in 5.0.1? I didn't have this problem in 4.5, but updated today and now it's here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17745) try to delete the content of the skeleton folder. It reside inside of the settingsfolder (~/.PyCharmxxxx.xx/system/python_stubs)
Removing/adding the python environment was not necessary for me. Simply restart PyCharm after removing the content (or the whole python_stubs folder)

This does the trick for me and now it works like a (py)charm again.

Answer (score 4):

That's a known, already reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15460

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import datetime
```

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Works for me.